# why my pip gives same error when i run Django server?

Tags: python, django, pip

I updated the version of my pip but when I run every time any command with pip on terminal, it gives me the same error. Before I tried to create a django project and after some time when I run project it gives error. I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 10, in <module>
    import uuid
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/uuid.py", line 57, in <module>
    _AIX     = platform.system() == 'AIX'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/platform.py", line 891, in system
    return uname().system
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/platform.py", line 857, in uname
    processor = _syscmd_uname('-p', '')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/platform.py", line 613, in _syscmd_uname
    output = subprocess.check_output(('uname', option),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
    process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
    shlex.split(command),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 311, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Every time it is the same error with pip. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/nir0s/distro/issues/222 ?

Comment: Are you using `pip` or `pip3`?